# I am getting an error loading a package in R as it says an older version of rlang is loaded but I have the newer version installed

Tags: r

I'm trying to load an R package and getting the following error:

namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

I have checked the version of rlang I have installed and it is showing as

> packageVersion('rlang')
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnnPT.png) '0.4.11'

Anyone know what might be happening here? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages involved and as part of this I tried manually installing rlang from the source just to make sure it was the correct version.

sessionInfo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnnPT.png)

Comment: Have you closed and restarted R as well? What package are you specifically trying to load? What does `sessionInfo` show just before you load the package?

Comment: Note that in addition to closing R (as MrFlick said), if you have multiple instances of R running and any one of them has loaded/attached `rlang`, then none of the running processes will be able to replace it. You must close all of them.

Comment: It's the hms package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hms/index.html)

Comment: I've tried loading an image of the sessionInfo - I'm not sure whether it worked though? I'm running the code in Alteryx, so the output looks a bit different to normal. I'll try closing everything down and seeing whether that resolves it

Comment: I'm loading a few packages and it seems to run fine except for the ones I've commented. I'm fairly new to R, so could one of the packages be loading an earlier version of rlang?
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)
#library(hms)
#library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
#library(readr)
library(cpp11)
library(forcats)
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(bit64)
library(zipangu)
library(exploratory)

Answer (score 1):

Remove rlang, shutdown and restart R, and then reinstall `rlang' using:

```
install.packages("rlang", dependencies = TRUE)
```

If you want to install the specific version then use ( 0.4.10 in current case):

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. Unfortunately uninstalling and reinstalling it isn't working. I've definitely got the latest version of rlang loaded. Looking at the session info I think this might be causing the issue
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
gplots_3.0.3       rlang_0.4.5        gdata_2.18.0       TunePareto_2.5    
It looks like gplots is loading an older version of rlang when I try and run the code

Comment: This looks like the same issue as https://support.bioconductor.org/p/46054/ .